# Circular/Radial Bounds for SciPy minimize function

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy

I am trying to use the SciPy minimize function from the optimize sub-module to optimize a surface equation bounded within a radius of 0.15 from the origin in the x-y plane.

```
ans = minimize(minimum_objective_3d, (.10,.10), args=(args), bounds=[(-.150,.150),(-.150,.150)])
```

I understand that the bounds argument that I am using specifies rectangular bounds for the operation. My question is... Is there a way to specify those bound instead as a circular radius centered at the origin?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Depends on the model. If the model can be expressed in terms of polar coordinates, you can put bounds on the distance.

Comment: Is there a way to establish the bounds as an inequality of x and y? as in sqrt(x^2 + y^2) <= radius?

Comment: That is not a bound but an inequality constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Erwin on the model transformation. There’s many solvers that support bound constraints and very few that support inequality constraints. If you still want to use the inequality constraint, then the COBYLA or SLSQP SciPy solvers support them. Or you can look into the Mystic optimization library (https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic).